# Let someone else manage my internet domain?

Tags: internet, domain

I would like to allow someone else to manage my domain names.  They would need complete technical access (change dns, etc), but I don't want to give them access to things like transfer, payment, or drop.

Does anyone know how I would do that?  I have them registered with GoDaddy right now, but am happy to move registrars or use whatever tools are available.

Thanks!

Comment: You would need to find a domain register that supports user accounts under a main account. I am pretty sure it exists but there might not be a great deal of demand for it. Currently this question is borderline of not being on topic, since I see no other way of answering the question, unless somebody suggests a domain register that supports this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Registrar is with GoDaddy, stick with GoDaddy. GoDaddy supports user accounts under the main account without revealing privileged information or personal private information (PPI). This administrative feature is called "AccountExec."

Further Reading(s):

[GoDaddy Support - Managing Domain Name Account Administrators](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3138/managing-domain-name-account-administrators)

[Giving Access to GoDaddy Account w/o Sharing Password](http://rtcamp.com/tutorials/accountexec-giving-access-to-godaddy-account-without-sharing-password/)